# Display fields (from query) on Swagger UI from complex record

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a complex record `SearchProductsRequest`  in a GET request that receives the parameters by query (
`/v1/products?ids=1,2,3&name=hombre&page=3&pageItems=4&sortField=name&sort=asc` ).

```cs
app.MapGet(
           $"/{ProductCatalogueApi.Version}/products",
           (SearchProductsRequest request)
                => ProductApiDelegates.SearchProducts(
                  request));
```

In the record, I've implemented the bind async
`public static ValueTask<SearchProductsRequest?> BindAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ParameterInfo parameter);` and now the parameters from the URL automatically convert the parameters to `SearchProductsRequest`.

The request is working as intended, but we are using (Swashbuckle -> ) Swagger UI for development.

Swagger UI does not recognize the members from `SearchProductsRequest` to display them as input boxes. Is there a way to make swagger UI know them and display them so a user consulting the swagger endpoint can pass value through it?

I was hoping to get the following:

[image: Endpoint with fields to add values]

Until now, I've only managed to have the fields displayed in swagger if I have all of them in the Map.Get() explicitly.

EDIT:

Adding asked content

Record:

```cs
public record SearchProductsRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<int>? Ids { get; private set; }

    public string? Name { get; private set; }

    public PaginationInfoRequest? PaginationInfo { get; private set; }

    public SortingInfoRequest? SortingInfo { get; private set; }

    public SearchProductsRequest(
        IEnumerable<int>? ids,
        string? name,
        PaginationInfoRequest? PaginationInfo,
        SortingInfoRequest? SortingInfo)
    {
        this.Ids = ids;
        this.Name = name;
        this.PaginationInfo = PaginationInfo;
        this.SortingInfo = SortingInfo;
    }

    public static ValueTask<SearchProductsRequest?> BindAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext,
        ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        var ids = ParseIds(httpContext);

        var name = httpContext?.Request.Query["name"] ?? string.Empty;

        PaginationInfoRequest? pagination = null;
        SortingInfoRequest? sorting = null;

        if (int.TryParse(httpContext?.Request.Query["page"], out var page)
            && int.TryParse(httpContext?.Request.Query["pageItems"], out var pageItems))
        {
            pagination = new PaginationInfoRequest(page, pageItems);
        }

        var sortField = httpContext?.Request.Query["sortField"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField))
        {
            sorting = new SortingInfoRequest(
                sortField,
                httpContext?.Request.Query["sort"].ToString() == "asc");
        }

        return ValueTask.FromResult<SearchProductsRequest?>(
            new SearchProductsRequest(
                ids,
                name!,
                pagination,
                sorting));
    }

#pragma warning disable SA1011 // Closing square brackets should be spaced correctly
    private static int[]? ParseIds(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        int[]? ids = null;

        var commaSeparatedIds = httpContext?.Request.Query["ids"]
                    .ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commaSeparatedIds))
        {
            ids = commaSeparatedIds
            .Split(",")
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<int>();
        }

        return ids;
    }
#pragma warning restore SA1011 // Closing square brackets should be spaced correctly
}
```

Delegate:

```cs
internal static async Task<IResult> SearchProducts(
        ILogger<ProductApiDelegates> logger,
        IMapper mapper,
        SearchProductsRequest request,
        IValidator<SearchProductsRequest> validator,
        IProductService productService)
    {
        using var activity = s_activitySource.StartActivity("Search products");
        var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(request);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = validationResult.GetErrors();
            logger.LogError("Bad Request: {Errors}", errors);
            return Results.BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Searching product details by name");
            var filtersContainer = mapper.Map<SearchProductsFiltersContainer>(request);
            var products = await productService.SearchProductsAsync(filtersContainer);
            if (products == null)
            {
                return Results.NotFound();
            }

            var searchProducts = BuildSearchProducts(mapper, products);
            var paginationInfo = await BuildPaginationInfo(filtersContainer, productService);
            var response = new SearchProductsResponse(searchProducts, paginationInfo);
            return Results.Ok(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "Error searching the products");
            return Results.Problem();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Mendonça, could you pls share how is your record and `ProductApiDelegates.SearchProducts`? What is your `BindAsync` also?

Comment: Hi @Rena. Sure, I've added the required information

Comment: Try to use the new [AsParameters] attribute

Comment: @T.Dominik, unfortunately, [AsParameters] is for .Net7. In some companies, LTS (Net6) is very important.

Comment: Workaround for .NET 6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878592/minimal-api-add-complex-parameters-into-swagger-ui or classic controllers