# Minimal API add complex parameters into swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

After defining the endpoint

```cs
app.MapGet($"{baseRoute}/GetProducts", GetProductsAsync)
.WithName("GetProducts")
.Produces<ProductResponseDto>()
.WithTags(Tag);
```

With this async method to call implementation.

```cs
private static async Task<IResult> GetProductsAsync(ProductsDto getProducts, IUserService userService)
{
    ProductResponseDto getProductsResponse = await userService.GetProductsAsync(getProducts);
    return Results.Ok(getProductsResponse);
}
```

I defined a basic BindAsync method for bind values.
I just want to add all fields contained in ProductsDto into swagger UI.
Is it possible?
If I use [FromQuery] annotation the Dto is null for every call. I am using .net core 6.

```
public class ProductsDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// clientId
    /// </summary>
    public int clientId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Test
    /// </summary>
    public int test { get; set; }

    public static ValueTask<ProductsDto> BindAsync(HttpContext context, ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        int.TryParse(context.Request.Query["clientId"], out var in_clientId);
        int.TryParse(context.Request.Query["test"], out var in_test);
        var result = new ProductsDto
        {
            clientId = in_clientId,
            test = in_test
        };
        return ValueTask.FromResult<ProductsDto?>(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add all relevant part including `ProductsDto` and desired url to be hit.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Using `[AsParameters]`. Related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters) here.

[image]

In .net 6, we can use custom model binding...

```
app.MapGet("/GetProducts2", (ProductsDto getProducts) =>
{
    return Results.Ok();
});

public class ProductsDto
{
    public int clientId { get; set; }
    public int test { get; set; }

    public static bool TryParse(string? value, IFormatProvider? provider, out ProductsDto? prod)
    {
        var segments = value?.Split(',',
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
        if (segments?.Length == 2
            && int.TryParse(segments[0], out var x)
            && int.TryParse(segments[1], out var y))
        {
            prod = new ProductsDto { clientId = x, test = y };
            return true;
        }

        prod = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will make the `ProductsDto recognized as a string`, and we can have `TryParse` method to handle the string and bind to the properties.

[image]

By the way, we can't use `[FromQuery]ProductsDto getProducts`. This will make the swagger UI show parameter like this which recognize `ProductsDto as a object`:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use .net core 6 which does not support [AsParameters].

Comment: then we need custom binding with `TryParse`

Comment: I updated my post with a workaround in .net 6

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the same results when using BindAsync?